# Symfony2 - retrieve old Entity after doctrine:mapping:import

Tags: eclipse, symfony, doctrine, restore

I generated the entities from existing database in Symfony2.
The problem is that one of the entities that I modified was erased with the one from the db table and I would like to retrieve the modifications.

Here is what I did:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AcmeBlogBundle annotation

php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

I tried to look in the local history but as the files were generated when I did the commands, there are not in the history.

Comment: I just could suggest maybe next time you should use git to maintain file history

Comment: Yes sure, I am usually using Mercurial for that, but it is a new project and I havent set yet the repository: My Mistake for sure...